# Hide section when comeback in history

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a homepage contains 2 sections are visible at first arrive, 2nd section is a portfolio gallery. 
After scrolling over section2, I hide my section1, and I only want section2 is visible from now on. When the guest clicks on single portfolio -> redirect to the detail portfolio page -> click back button to go back home (at this point I only want section2 is visible).

```
  //Before click on portfolio 
  history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
  //After rediecting to portfolio detail, click back triggers
  window.history.back();
```

I have successfully hidden my section1 as when scrolling over the section2, but when I come back from detail portfolios which is near the top it shows me at top section1 again.

Is there any chance that I can hide my section1 through history or by any tricks, Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can add a variable to localStorage, when you go to section 2, and if that variable exists on  next load, then you hide section 1?

Comment: @callback: Thanks very much, I've just done some search and start using it now. It seems to work.

Comment: I put my comment as an answer. If it answers your question, mark it as accepted so that other users benefit from it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you to the section 2 page, you can save it in localStorage using:

`window.localStorage.setItem('visitedSection', '2');`

On load of the page, you can check the localStorage and then hide the section 1 accordingly,

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  var visitedSection = window.localStorage.getItem('visitedSection');
  if (visitedSection && visitedSection === '2') {
    $(section1Selector).hide(); //replace section1Selector with the appropriate selector
  }
});
```